# Reference counting GC in languages with pointer arithmetic

Tags: programming-languages, garbage-collection, reference-counting

I was wondering if it is possible to implement reference counting-based GC in languages which allow pointer arithmetic. For example (this is pseudo-C),

```
int* f()
{
    int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *ptr = array + 3;
    return ptr;
}
```

Will it be ever possible for a compiler to manage memory correctly in this scenario?

Comment: @Heandel How is compiler ever be able to verify that? That should be runtime's job.

Comment: GC'd languages typically do not GC local, stack based variables. That's why you have to create GC'd objects with new. So this isn't a good example.

Comment: @Neil How so? C#, Java, Ruby, Python, etc. -- all GC locals.

Comment: @Anton : if you do not have a mechanism to enforce a pointer to always point to a *valid* object you cannot do reference counting. This mechanism can be split between both runtime and compile-time (for example, refuse manual pointer adress affectation).

Comment: @Anton: what Neil means, I think, is that GC for automatic POD types, i.e. stack cleanup, is too trivial to be called GC. If you do call it GC, then C and C++ have GC.

Comment: @larsmans, both CLR and JVM are looking for roots in stack and registers, at least. Strictly it can be said that stacks are GC-managed. Nevertheless, there is such a little use for reference counting that I don't think it worth trying to implement such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible in general. Suppose you use the [XOR trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_linked_list) to implement linked lists; then the pointers are still around "implicitly" (can be reconstructed), but the GC cannot find them without knowledge of how the XOR trick works and when it is being used. It may think the number of references is zero for each element. To trick a GC that does have knowledge of the XOR trick, devise a variant by e.g. including some kind of salt in the XOR.

Also, consider how reference-counted C would have to handle this:

```
void *ptr = WHATEVER;      // first reference
uintptr_t ptr_temp = ptr;  // second reference
unsigned char ptr_copy[sizeof(uintptr_t)];
memcpy(ptr_copy, ptr_temp, sizeof(uintptr_t)); // third reference
```

Every general-purpose GC for C/C++ uses heuristics to cope with pointer arithmetic tricks. See, for example, the [conservative GC of Hans Boehm](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/). *Conservative* means here that it considers just about everything a potential pointer.

Comment: A trivial reference-counting "GC" (not sure if it deserves this name) does not need to recognise pointers, it is done already by simply knowing their types. You have to increase a counter each time an address is taken and decrease when it is dropped. In theory you can do this in presense of a pointer arithmetics, but with a significant penalty on memory and a complicated compiler.

Comment: @SK-logic: while you wrote your comment, I was typing what I think is a counterexample to your argument.

Comment: of course you won't be able to do so without a typed memory (which implies severe restrictions on a language itself). But still, it will be a pointer arithmetics. Once it is translated into something like LLVM-style GEPs, it is much easier to reason about it.